# define an integration function in python

Tags: python, function, numerical-integration

My code is:

```
def A_GW_onelevel(nw):
    G4=1.0/(nw-0.001j-(x**2/(nw-x**2/w_b+w_b-0.001j)))
    return nw*(1.0/(math.pi))*abs(G4.imag)

def TotalEnergy_GW_onelevel(x):
    GW,err=quad(A_GW_onelevel,-4.0,0.0)
    return GW
for x in (0.1*i for i in xrange(40)):
    print TotalEnergy_GW_onelevel(x)
    plot(x, TotalEnergy_GW_onelevel(x))

show()
```

What I want to do is plot the function `TotalEnergy_GW_onelevle(x)=\int d(nw) A_GW_onelevel(nw)`

but this code does work. I tried other methods but still cannot find the correct way. I just started doing programming work.

It gives the correct TotalEnergy_GW_onelevel(x) value. But it does not plot anything. In the plotting, there is nothing except the two axis.

Comment: *but this code does work*. Then what is the problem? :-) If the code does **not** work, you need to tell us *how* it doesn't work. Does it throw an exception? Do you see incorrect values? What do you *expect* to see?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters ok, I find some mistake. quad will give two output. integration result and errors. We should take only integration result so that the dimension of x and y in plot will be the same. But still does not give me the correct plotting. There is nothing on the figure except the two axis...

Comment: You could start by adding some `print` statements so you see what output is produced by a function for a given input.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters yes I did but actually it the TotalEnergy_GW_onelevel(x) values are correct...

Comment: You may need to turn on hold for the plotting, since you're looping over and plotting many individual points. Or you could just compute all the values and plot the vector in one go.

Comment: @M4rtini I am sorry I do not understand what do you mean. Turn on hold for plotting?

Comment: @sky  It a property that defines if the plot is cleared of previous data when plot is called. See matplotlib docs for more info: http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot

Comment: @M4rtini Got it... I need to arrange the two variables in a list by append(x) and append (otalEnergy_GW_onelevle(x)) then plot it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yup, although list comprehension would be better than appending one and one value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
X = [0.1*i for i in xrange(40)]
Y = [TotalEnergy_GW_onelevel(x) for x in X]
plot(X,Y)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I need to learn a lot on the way of thinking when I am programming... I need to learn how to make my code faster and more efficient.